# how to get the attributes of an existing mutex? (pthread library)

Tags: pthreads, mutex

For debugging purposes I'd like to see what kind of mutex a certain pthread mutex is.
E.g. if it is PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE or PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK etc.

You can obtain this information via pthread_mutexattr_gettype but then you need to have access to the pthread_mutexattr_t but there's no pthread_mutex_get_attr (or even pthread_mutex_get_attr_np) function.

The solution does not need to be portable over operating systems (linux, macos) but preferably work on recent compilers (gcc 8 and later).

Comment: Are you concerned that the mutex might have different attributes than you specified, or is it that there is some reason for uncertainty about what attributes were specified?

Comment: In any event, indeed no, there is no `pthread_mutex_get_attr()` or equivalent, and there is no particular reason to expect that a `pthread_mutex_t` retains attributes in the form of an attributes object.  The mutex attributes you present to `pthread_mutex_init()` should be regarded as instructions for that function, not as data to be recorded in the mutex object.  Nevertheless, you can try to inspect the `pthread_mutex_t` to see what information you can glean.

Comment: Hi John, two reasons: it's a big application and I also wonder if things get corrupt. Furthermore: I also developed a locking-tracer (to aid the debugging proces) and it would be useful extra information for its output (it also allows me to ignore certain "locked twice" errors). There's valgrind drd/helgrind as well, but depending on how you trace my program is 3 upto 20 times faster (still testing though).